# Make screen brighter when phone is raised?

Tags: lock-screens, screen-brightness

When raising my Google Pixel XL (latest Android Pie), without pressing anything, it already shows the clock, weather, battery percentage etc. -- that's nice. However, the screen at that point is also very dim, much too dark, with the clock barely visible when outside. I've tried adjusting various brightness settings (making it brighter, toggling adaptive brightness) but they all seem to be unconnected to this raising-screen, they all just make it brighter once I click a button or unlock. Is there a way to increase the raised-screen brightness, though? Thanks!