# Increase brightness when display is too dark to recognize anything

Tags: screen-brightness

Any mechanism that **doesn’t require seeing the display** would be good. When I’m outside under sun and the phone brightness is at low level, I simply can’t recognize anything. The only currently feasible way is to remember where the slider will show up and operate it blindly. Better would be if it could be done by using

- the hardware buttons,
- swipe gestures,
- motion-based gestures or
- voice recognition

to name a few examples. It only needs to **set brightness to maximum** as any finer adjustment can be done using the slider as a subsequent step.

This question might be related to [Make screen brighter when phone is raised?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/201822/make-screen-brighter-when-phone-is-raised) though (given that the question didn’t receive any response in the 4 years) I’m making the requirement broader (not limited to “raising the screen”) in the hope there might be a solution with a different approach.

The phone in question is [Google Pixel](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/7158570?hl=en&ref_topic=7530176#zippy=%2Cpixel) (2016, upgraded to Android 10).

Comment: Does your phone misses a brightness sensor which automatically increases/decreases brightness or does the automatic screen brightness does not properly on your phone?

Comment: It does automatically change brightness a bit, but since I normally decrease brightness when I’m indoors, its slight brightness increase when outdoors is not sufficient to reach/surpass the necessary brightness level

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Edge Gesture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ss.edgegestures) to set a gesture to increase/decrease the screen brightness. Download the app, give it the necessary permission.

Set `Pull and Slide` (i.e. for the left edge) to `Brightness control`.

[image]

It is possible to combine the app with automation apps such as [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) or [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) if you really want to create flows or macro that set the brightness to 100% immediately via gestures.

**Disclaimer:** I am just a user of the aforementioned apps.